# BitBucket Hook blocks good commits

Tags: git, bitbucket, pre-commit-hook

I've setup "Push check" to allow commits with `BDAASA-<NUMBER>: <COMMIT MESSAGE>` or `Revert "BDAASA-<NUMBER>: <COMMIT MESSAGE>"` to be only accepted:

[image]

My regex syntax: `(BDAASA-\d{4,5}:.*)|(Revert "BDAASA-\d{4,5}:.*")` is ok when testing online:

[image]

But when I want to add my two new commits:

[image]

I'm being blocked with my hook:

[image]

Am I missing something here? Thx for help!

**Update:**

Even `(BDAASA-\d{4,5}: .*)|(.*)` does not work and it basically should accept anything ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that you have to uncheck `Enable the syntax check for each commit message` as it is checking even historic commits which are not part of the push.

Now every regex works as expected.